# How to put constraints for variables of the loop in PowerShell?

Tags: loops, powershell, conditional-statements

I have the following code:

```
$SE = 215

function F
{
    Param ($OE)
    For ($iteration = 1; $iteration -le 100; $iteration++)
    {
        Write-host "Iteration" $iteration
        $result = $OE - 1
        $OE = $result
        $result

        ForEach ($input in $result)
        {
            $OPT = 5 * [double]$Steel.Force * 1000 * ([math]::pow([double]$Steel.L, 4))/(384 * $input * ([math]::pow(10, 9)) * [double]$Steel.I * ([math]::pow(10, -8)))
            $OPT
        }
    }
}
F -OE $SE
```

I want to put constraints for two variables: `$result` and `$OPT`. For example, when `$result -le 205` and/or `$OPT -ge 5` the iteration will stop. Currently, the iteration will keep running until `$iteration = 100`. I have tried to add a `do{} While()` loop, but it did not work. Sometimes the script is stuck. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` to exit a loop.

For example:

```
if ($result -le 205 -and $OPT -ge 5) { break }
```

You can read more about it here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847873.aspx

Comment: If I put this code after the `ForEach loop. It actually can only break when `$OPT -ge 5`. But I will do some further study about it. Thank you.